# Facebook - Relationship Status showing on my timeline but not viewable to all friends

Tags: facebook, status

I updated my relationship status to in a relationship the evening of 12/7. I made sure to update who could view the status change from “only me” to “my friends” and clicked save. I was able to then see the status on my timeline. I have a screen shot. It was not visible to friends for 12+ hours but rather became visible sometime later as only then the post began to receive activity from friends. On 12/8 I added a new friend, but this in a relationship status update was not visible when they went to view my page. All other posts were showing. I added another friend on 12/10 and this friend also wasn’t able to view this timeline post showing in a relationship but could see all others. How? Why? I did not touch, edit, update or change anything and this wasn’t showing for multiple friends. I triple checked everything selected to ensure this post was selected to show to my friends on Facebook and it still wasn’t visible. Why did this happen? I need to know why the system wouldn’t show this post as visible to all friends as I had selected.